# A subsequence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ partial sum sequence that converges, implies $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence of reals and let  $(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be its partial sum sequence.
> Is there a sequence $(n_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ of natural numbers s.t: 
> $i. \space$ $(n_j - n_{j-1})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.
> $ii.$ $(S_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$
> $iii.$ If $(S_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$

*(Let's assume that $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}:2 < n_j - n_{j-1}$ so it's not trivial).*

We've proved in class that if there exists a sequence $(n_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ which satisfies $i$, $ii$, $(S_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges, and *we are given* that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ then $(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. 
Therefore, my interest is to know if we can always convert the convergence's question of $(S_k)_{k \in\mathbb{N}}$ with a sequence $(S_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not generally hold. Let
$$a_n = \begin{cases} -1 & n = 0 \mod 3 \\ 0 & n = 1 \mod 3 \\ 1 & n = 2 \mod 3\end{cases}.$$
It is clear that the sequence $(S_n) = (-1,-1,0,-1,-1,0,...)$.

The subsequences where $S_{n_j}$ converges are when the $n_j$ are $0,1\mod 3$ after a certain $N$ or $2 \mod 3$ after a certain $N$, but since $a_n$ does not converge ever, this result can never hold.

If you have $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 0$, I think your result should hold though.

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know.